# How to define a macro to use with struct array C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, macros

I've defined a macro to set my values(C code), for example:

```
.h file

typedef struct {
    uint8_t details;
    uint8_t info[20];
} values_struct;

#define INIT_VALUES_STRUCT(X) values_struct X = {.details = 0x00, .info = { 0x01 } }

.c file

INIT_VALUES_STRUCT(pro_struct);
```

but I need to set a "struct array" like:

```
values_struct pro_struct[10];
```

and to set default values with a macro, it's possible and how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine that macro as

```
#define INIT_VALUES_STRUCT {.details = 0x00, .info = { 0x01 } }
```

And then you can have

```
struct values_struct pro_struct = INIT_VALUES_STRUCT;
struct values_struct pro_struct_arr[] = { INIT_VALUES_STRUCT,
                                          INIT_VALUES_STRUCT,
                                          INIT_VALUES_STRUCT };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it complicated with macros when the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct x {
    uint8_t details;
    uint8_t info[2];
};
int main(void) {
   struct x arr[2] = {
       { 1, {5, 6}},
       { 3, {4, 7}}

    };
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because macros are a good way telling  your c code you have these const variables, global variables, global functions, etc.. you share and use in your entire program.It's much more cleaner to use `#define VAL 1 ` in you foo.h file rather than const int value = 1 or use global function/constructors etc.

Comment: IMHO `const int value = 1` is better than a macro as the compiler knows its type along with its value. Perhaps writing `const int VALUE = 1` is slightly better

Comment: In the end you know that the preprocessor will replace the value/code you define in the places you used your macro.It's almost the same semantic but the code will be more unclean in my perspective and i'm sure i'm not the only c programmer who thinks this. It's just a convention.. you are free to use what ever you want.

Comment: In the case of a structure, a macro-ed initializer is far more readable then the hard-coded one. Not to mention that using a macro means you aren't obligated to change numerous object initializations if you happen to change the structure definition.

Comment: Btw
For the actual compiled code, with any modern compiler, there should be zero performance difference between the two.

Comment: The trouble with macros is that you do not have type information. Consider `#define WIBBLE 1`then `#define WOBBLE 12'  compared to `typedef int MyErrorCode; ty[edef int AnotherOne; const MyErrorCode WIBBLE = 1; const AnotherOne WOBBLE=12;` - With marcos a typo will not be picked up

Comment: @EdHeal, we are talking about very different use cases. For the case of structure initialziers, your points don't really apply as much.

Comment: The same logic applies.

Comment: No it doesn't, a structure initializer carries no type information, since `c` structures are not nominally equivalent. And the typo is in fact more likely to occur if an initizlaer is copy pasted all over the place, instead of using the macro.